# Removing seasonality from multiple time series

Tags: time-series, model, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

I'm building a model involving a few times series, let's call them A and B. I removed seasonality from A using a function with a linear trend, days of the week and statistically significant months. However, for the series B days of the week don't have any effect and different months are statistically significant.
Is there any reason why using different seasonality functions would for different time series **in the same model** would be a bad idea? Intuitively it shouldn't be a problem, the end product are deseasonalised time series and we don't need to care how we got them - but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the idea is to use a common seasonal filter to IDENTIFY the way y and x relate since the original cross-correlation defies analysis due to auto-correlative structure. The reason for the common filter is to not distort the IDENTIFICATION of the underlying predictive effect/model between the two original series. .

Comment: I don't think I understand. So what you're saying is that I shouldn't use different seasonalities, because then I won't be able to identify the relation between x and y? Why is that the case?

Comment: To clarify we make X and Y stationary by applying the appropriate differencing operator which MIGHT BE NOT THE SAME . After this step then build and ARMA model for the stationary X use use that on the stationary Y . You now have two new series to cross-correlate to IDENTIFY the relationship between the original Y and X